# 2 Full Screen Divs with float left

Tags: css

I am trying to make a UL or DIV's where each list item / child div is full screen (100% width 100% height) and floated left so i can scroll horizontally through them, any idea how I can do this? here is my code but it is not working as I had thought

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="site-holder">

   <div class="toronto-full">
   TESTING
   </div>

   <div class="montreal-full">
   TESTING
   </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html { width:150%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
body { width:150%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }

#site-holder { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; float:left; }

.toronto-full {background-color:green; width:50%; height:100%; float:left; }
.montreal-full {background-color:red; width:50%; height:100%; float:left; }
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: I think you should use javascript to set the width and height of the child elements manually.

Comment: Are the pages to scroll vertically or horizontally?

Comment: they should scroll horizontally

Comment: In your example, are the two pages to be scrolled: `.toronto-full` and `.montreal-full`?

Comment: Yes sir! both should be floated left so i can scroll horizontally

Comment: Don't assume they need to be floated left. There are other solutions. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GKfUJ/1/)**

Try this:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#site-holder {
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
}

.toronto-full, .montreal-full {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; /* this line added in edit */
    font-size: initial;
}
.toronto-full {
    background: green;
}
.montreal-full {
    background: red;
}
```

**EDIT**:
Review the code again. I added a line which fixes the problem with vertical mismatch of the divs.

Comment: Winner Winner Chicken Dinner!

Comment: Can you provide an example fiddle?

Comment: one more question, when I add anything to the .toronto-full div, its pushes the montreal div down, any idea why?

Comment: You sir, are a CSS god

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even want to use float for this?

You could use `inline-block` display;

```
.toronto-full {
    background-color:green;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.montreal-full {
    background-color:red;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7DxFE/

Comment: I need .toronto-full & .montreal-full to occupy the full screen, so that when toronto is visible, I cant see montreal, but I can scroll horizontally over to reveal it

Comment: In your example I can see both, I only want to see one at a time